Change icon size in lightning-tab
<template>
     <lightning-tabset class="red-icon">
          <lightning-tab label="My Messages" icon-name='utility:notification'>
          </lightning-tab>
     </lightning-tabset>
</template>

.red-icon{
    --slds-c-icon-color-foreground-default:red;
}

I successfully changed the color of the icon in my lighting-tab using this styling hook, but I am struggling to make the icon smaller, ideally xx-small.
I think the answer might be to use renderedCallback to change the style after the icon is rendered, but so far I haven't been able to change it.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Unfortunately you don't have control over icon size in lightning-tab via styling hooks
What you can do is to create Static Resource and override styles this way.
component-name .slds-icon--small {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}

and then load this static resource in component, you can use static variable to make sure to load resource only once
import myResource from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/resourceReference";
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import sample from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/sample";
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class MiscStaticResource extends LightningElement {

  // Expose URL of assets included inside an archive file
  einsteinUrl = sample + "/styles/styles.css";
  static isLoaded = false;

  async connectedCallback() {
     try {
       await loadStyle(this, sampleStyles);
       MiscStaticResource.isLoaded = true;
     }
     catch(e) {
       console.error(e);
     }    
  }
}


Thanks for your help ytiq! I was able to do pretty much what you suggested in the renderedCallback function
renderedCallback() {
     let tabset = this.template.querySelector('lightning-tabset');

     if (!tabset) {
          return;
     }

     tabset.classList.add('custom-tabset-style');

     let style = document.createElement('style');
     style.innerText = `
          .custom-tabset-style .slds-icon_small {
               width: 0.7rem;
               height: 0.7rem;
          }
     `;

     tabset.appendChild(style);
}


